# Excel Attachment not working in Inline Attachment in microsoft bot dot net

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I am working on Microsoft dot net BOT. I am having an issue while sending Inline excel attachment in the BOT. I am having excel file in my project.

I am getting the only link like "TestBOT.xlsx". But if I click on the link, excel is not downloading.

Below is my code.

```
        var imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/docs/TestBOT.xlsx");
        var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));
        return new Attachment
        {
            Name = "TestBOT.xlsx",
            ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            ContentUrl = $"data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,{imageData}"

        };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it specific on a channel? Is it the same with the emulator?

Comment: By the way, I think that for xlsx, ContentType should be "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Comment: @NicolasR , I tried both _italic_application/vnd.ms-excel_italic_ and _italic_application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet_italic_, but nothing worked for me. I tried in emulator and WebChat channel

Comment: @NicolasR, Also i tried 
`code`private static Attachment GetInlineAttachment(string path)
        {
            var imagePath = path;
            return new Attachment
            {
                Name = "Bot.xlsx",
                ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                ContentUrl = path,
            };
        }
--
   Attachment attch= null;
                    string Sfilename = @"E:/Bot.xlsx";
                    attachment = GetInlineAttachment(Sfilename);
                    reply.Attachments.Add(attch);`code`